# How Lord Buddha did sermon for the people who was long distance

Tags: reference-request, the-buddha, books, metaphysics

If my memory is correct, Lord Buddha did a sermon for the long-distance people. It is mentioned that Lord Budha can do a sermon even for someone in another solar system. How is it possible? Because to travel sound to long-distance takes time(possibly years). Can someone give me an answer with references from Tripitaka?

Comment: I believe the Buddha is often said to have visitors, either celestial bodhisattvas or gods. either could be construed as visionary experiences, rather than aliens i mean. can't recall him ever leaving India, though it's sometimes said his buddha body manifests in other worlds.

Answer (score 1):

No.

3 points:

1. Lord Buddha did not give any long-distance sermons.
2. Not all stories are to be taken literally.
3. I cannot give you any reference for something that did not happen.